# Visualizing feature distributions using ggplot2

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have a dataset with two groups. For comparison purposes, I would like to visualize the distribution of feature values for each group on the same plot. Here's the dataframe in the current form.

```
Group Feature  Frequency
A     Feature1 0.000221
B     Feature1 0.044112
A     Feature2 0.009346
B     Feature2 0.039939
A     Feature3 0.010597
B     Feature3 0.020723
```

How can I reshape this so that each feature is a row, and each group is a column? The following is the dataframe I need for a scatterplot.

```
Feature  FreqA     FreqB
Feature1 0.000221 0.044112
Feature2 0.009346 0.039939
Feature3 0.010597 0.020723
```

This dataset has about 100 features.

Comment: ggplot(df, aes(x=write,y=read,colour=sex)+geom_point()

Comment: This is more a question for Stack Overflow, but I'd recommend Hadley Wickham's `tidyr` package.  It has functions like `spread` and `gather` for doing these kinds of operations.

Answer (score 0):

```
dfA <- df[df$Group == 'A',]
dfB <- df[df$Group == 'B',]

dfA$Group <- NULL
dfB$Group <- NULL

dfBoth <- merge(dfA,dfB, by="Feature")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to plot it, there is no need to reshape the data. You can do something like this: 
`ggplot(data,aes(Frequency)) + geom_density() + facet_wrap(~Feature)` (or `~Group` depending on what you're trying to do)